# "....but that the dread of something after death,the undiscovered country from whose border no traveler returns,puzzles the will..."

Tags: word-usage, clauses, relative-clauses, coordinating-conjunctions

I am having a hard time identifying the particular clause type.

**What type of clause is the part "from whose...returns"?**

Comment: That should be "bourne", not "border".

Answer (score 1):

I believe that would be a Dependent Relative Clause, also known as a Dependent Adjective Clause. We can know this because the clause can't stand alone (making it dependent) and it describes a noun (the undiscovered country, making it relative/adjective). A clear and concise link to understand the differences between dependent clauses can be found [here](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/nounclauses/).

Comment: But if it is an adjective clause shouldn't the conjunction whose be placed immediately after country?

Comment: @archangel89 Not necesarrily. English is filled with exceptions. The rule for adjective clauses is that the relative pronoun *usually* is first in the clause. It can follow a preposition, in this case being 'from'.